# Problems with loading tidyverse (object 'pkgInfo' not found)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to install tidyverse, but am running into some problems. This is the console output:

```
install.packages("tidyverse", lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/tidyverse_1.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 440022 bytes (429 KB)
downloaded 429 KB


package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in C:\Users\21sco\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQL8MAr\downloaded_packages

library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
object 'pkgInfo' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.0.3
2: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
package ‘stringi’ has no 'package.rds' in Meta/
```

I had installed and used tidyverse a few months ago with no issues, other than that packages were being installed by default to my onedrive. This happened initially here too, but I changed the path to a different folder (which fixed it before too) and attempted to modify my R profile to make the change permanent (unsuccessful). I also just tried deleting both R and RStduio to see if this fixes it, however the issue remains the same. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related post? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972249/680068

Comment: I did see this before posting. It appears to be a similar issue (i.e. caused by syncing problems between documents and cloud backup), unfortunately however none of these fixes worked for me