# Loading readR packaged failed

Tags: r, install.packages, readr

I installed readr package using the following code -

```
install.packages('readr',dependencies = T)
```

It installed succesfully. However, when I tried to load the package, it failed and showed the following error message -

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 object 'pkgInfo' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  package ‘ellipsis’ has no 'package.rds' in Meta/
```

Not sure how to fix this!! Tried removing the package and reinstalling but didn't work.

I have been using this package for a while. Never had any issues before. But suddenly unable to load.

Comment: You need to check version of 'readr' and version of R. You can see some information from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html
if 'readr' version is 2.1, it requires R version is higher than 3.1.

Comment: @cnp, my R version is 4.1.2

Comment: try to download zip file from my link and install from zip file. Sometimes, I have similar problem. I have to install from zip file.

Comment: @cnp, tried that but still similar error. But figured out the issue. It was a libpath issue. Once I fixed the libpath, it loaded properly

Comment: Related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967560/object-pkginfo-not-found-r/51972249#51972249

Comment: Write up your libpath problem and fix as an answer and accept it for others in the future.

Comment: @zx8754, yes. similar to that but mine was synced to One Drive. Readr folder and the meta folder within Ellipsis were not synced so R couldn't access them. Once I changed my libpath to a folder that wasn't synced to One Dirve, and reinstalled Readr. I was able to load the package after that.

Answer (score 1):

My default library location for R is synced to onedrive and for some reason Readr folder and the Meta folder within Ellipsis were not synced so R couldn't access them.

Once I changed my libpath (using .libPaths function) to a folder that wasn't synced to One Dirve, and reinstalled Readr. I was able to load the package without any issues.